# When Deployment Target Is 8.0 Or 8.1 There Comes A Warning For The Method Defined In SWRevealViewController.m

Tags: objective-c, json, ios10

```
@implementation SWContextTransitionObject
{
    __weak SWRevealViewController *_revealVC;
    UIView *_view;
    UIViewController *_toVC;
    UIViewController *_fromVC;
    void (^_completion)(void);
}
```

Comment: Warning : Method 'targetTransform' in protocol 'UIViewControllerContextTransitioning' not implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at Apple's documentation about `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning`: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollercontexttransitioning/1622036-targettransform?language=objc

As you can see `targetTransform` was added with iOS 8 which you're required to implement:

> Returns a transform indicating the amount of rotation being applied during the transition.

---

**Edit**: As requested here's an example code that you could use to indicate that your transition requires no rotation:

```
- (CGAffineTransform)targetTransform
{
    return CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```

Comment: thanks but i want some more detail to short out this issue because of i am new ....i got some solution but not working which is following            Right after @implementation enter the following code :

- (CGAffineTransform)targetTransform  {

return self.targetTransform; }

Comment: That makes no sense, as you're trying to return the property that would have been returned anyways if it would exist. See my edited answer for an example of what you could return here.

Comment: @Manishpatel no problem. If that answers your question could you please accept my answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me, this helped:

https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/356

In SWRevealViewController.m add:

```
@implementation SWContextTransitionObject

- (void)pauseInteractiveTransition {
    // not supported
}
```